# Как получить файл присланный пользователем боту в Telegram на java?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Нужно скачать файл присланный пользователем боту на сервер и положить его в заданную пользователем папку.
Можно получить объект типа `Document` вот так 
`Document doc = update.getMessage().getDocument();` но как его загрузить на сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
public void uploadFile(String file_name, String file_id) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/getFile?file_id="+file_id);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( url.openStream())); 
    String res = in.readLine();
    JSONObject jresult = new JSONObject(res);
    JSONObject path = jresult.getJSONObject("result");
    String file_path = path.getString("file_path");
    URL downoload = new URL("https://api.telegram.org/file/bot" + token + "/" + file_path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(upPath + file_name);
    System.out.println("Start upload");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(downoload.openStream());
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    fos.close();
    rbc.close();
    uploadFlag = 0;
    System.out.println("Uploaded!");
}
```